# pgfplots colorbar does not render labels in fixed format when used with ymode=log

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Considering the MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    point meta min=0.1,
    point meta max=0.48,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        scaled y ticks=false,
        ymode=log,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=2
        },
    },
]
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

pgfplots really jumps through some hoops here to present an awkward result. Obviously, `ymode=linear` works as expected, but `ymode=log` renders `0.10` as `10^{-1.00}` (unfortunately, TeX math input does not work here, but you get the idea).

Comment: add `log ticks with fixed point` to the `colorbar style` options ...

Comment: Works, although I guess options like `fixed zerofill` are not supported. Can you add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538958/pgfplots-colorbar-does-not-render-labels-in-fixed-format-when-used-with-ymode-lo?noredirect=1#comment1361729_538958) you can achieve this by adding `log ticks with fixed point` to the `colorbar style` options.

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        point meta min=0.1,
        point meta max=0.48,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
            scaled y ticks=false,
            ymode=log,
            log ticks with fixed point,
        },
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you. Besides [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓), you can also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score).